# Android JSON request populating array

Tags: android, json

I have followed this tutorial.

The author directly uses the data in the callback by setting the textview within the callback. What I would like to do is populate an array with the response I'm getting from my request, and then be able to use that array elsewhere (as the response listener is an anonymous inner class, I can't figure out how to get data from it; any attempt to assign to an array inside the listener has proved fruitless.

Thanks, please bear with me as I'm still a beginner.

The listener:

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(urlJsonArry,
        new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {
                    // Parsing json array response
                    // loop through each json object
                    jsonResponse = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response
                                .get(i);

                        String name = person.getString("name");
                        String email = person.getString("email");
                        JSONObject phone = person
                                .getJSONObject("phone");
                        String home = phone.getString("home");
                        String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");

                        jsonResponse += "Name: " + name + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Email: " + email + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Home: " + home + "\n\n";
                        jsonResponse += "Mobile: " + mobile + "\n\n\n";

                    }

                    txtResponse.setText(jsonResponse);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                hidepDialog();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                hidepDialog();
            }
        });
```

EDIT: The code below outlines the problem I'm having. I'm aware this is probably due to misunderstanding or misapplication on my part but still.

```
private void makeJsonArrayRequest(String url){

    //ONLY WAY TO ACCESS INSIDE LISTENER IS TO MAKE FINAL

    final ArrayList<String> string = new ArrayList<>();

    showpDialog();
    JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(
            url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject field = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                            string.add(i,  field.getString("title"));

                            //THIS PRINTS OUT ALL MY TITLES CORRECTLY, SHOWING THAT 
                            //THE STRINGS ARRAY IS POPULATED IN THIS SCOPE

                            Log.d(AppController.TAG, string.get(i));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(context,
                                "Error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    hidepDialog();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(AppController.TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                    error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 hidepDialog();
                }
            }
    );

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);

    //THIS CAUSES AN OUT OF BOUNDS EXCEPTION, AS IT THINKS THE ARRAY HAS NOT BEEN POPULATED

    Log.d(AppController.TAG, string.get(3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is using variable string as a copy of actual string inside OnResponse(..).

Try adding static to this variable :

```
 final static ArrayList<String> string = new ArrayList<>();
```